# Mountains are where we belong to

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is a correct sentence,

> Mountains are where we belong to.

or,

> Mountains are where we belong.

Comment: We usually speak of belonging _in_ a place or a particular type of landscape, not _to_ it. _Mountains are where we belong = We belong in the mountains._

Comment: Also, prepositions are not something to end a sentence with (well, classically).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Only prescriptively. This rule has almost never been in practice anywhere among native speakers. It's just one that teachers beat their students over the head *with*, while being unable to stop themselves from breaking the rule. And that's not the problem here

Answer (score 1):

We don't belong *to* the mountains.  That would mean that the mountains own us...and I am not owned by any landform.

We might belong in the mountains.  This means that the mountains are the good and natural place for us.  And, idiomatically, you can express that as:

> The mountains are where I belong.

Comment: There is a song named "I belong to Glasgow" by Will Fyfe. Why is there "belong to" In that place?

Comment: Because it is a song.  He is saying that he is owned by the city, in a metaphorical way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "*Mountains are **where** we belong to*" is that "where" is an adverbial, and it usually represents a prepositional phrase, like "in the mountains". So, with "where", the sentence means, *"We belong in the mountains to*" or "*We belong to in the mountains*", both of which are nonsense, grammatically.

With the meaning of "*We belong to the mountains*", you could say, "*The mountains are **what** we belong to*".